# Azure SQL Database sys.resource_stats :: LAST_VALUE(storage_in_megabytes)

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm creating a query that allows me to dig into the logs of the last 2 weeks of an Azure SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) -- 7 Days

SELECT DISTINCT
   MAX(database_name) AS DatabaseName
  ,MAX(sku) AS PlatformTier
  ,max(storage_in_megabytes) AS StorageMB 
  ,MIN(end_time) AS StartTime
  ,MAX(end_time) AS EndTime
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_CPU
  ,MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS Max_CPU
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [CPU Fit %]
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_IO
  ,MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS Max_IO
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Data IO Fit %]
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_LogWrite
  ,MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS Max_LogWrite
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Log Write Fit %]
  
FROM sys.resource_stats
WHERE start_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY database_name
```

The problems arrive in the `line max(storage_in_megabytes) AS StorageMB` because it is taking the **Maximum** value of the last 2 weeks. That doesn't represent the current database size.

I would like  to use `LAST_VALUE` but I don't know how to as there is no `row_number()`.

Otherwise some:

```
SELECT TOP 1 storage_in_megabytes
    ,*
FROM sys.resource_stats
ORDER BY end_time DESC
```

In the select but that too needs to be aggregated by something.

I'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated TOP 1 subquery to get the current storage size like below. This example also groups by the database attributes that are not aggregated (database_name and sku).

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) -- 7 Days

SELECT
   database_name AS DatabaseName
  ,sku AS PlatformTier
  ,(SELECT TOP 1 storage_in_megabytes FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs2 WHERE rs2.database_name = rs1.database_name ORDER BY rs2.start_time DESC)  AS StorageMB 
  ,MIN(end_time) AS StartTime
  ,MAX(end_time) AS EndTime
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_CPU
  ,MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS Max_CPU
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [CPU Fit %]
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_IO
  ,MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS Max_IO
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Data IO Fit %]
  ,CAST(AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_LogWrite
  ,MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS Max_LogWrite
  ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Log Write Fit %]
  
FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs1
WHERE start_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY database_name, sku
ORDER BY database_name, sku;
```

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman, not sure why but the `sku` is returning 2 rows per database name: Standard & Premium for each database.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, the multiple rows is probably due to sku being changed at some point since the start_time parameter (e.g. scale up/down).